# Section number not appearing

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

Disclaimer: Essentially none of the code is original to me; I got it from various places online (for example, the nice looking TOC was from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446780/toc-chapter-numbers-with-different-color-and-background).)

**My problem:** The section number is not appearing in my document. I am pretty sure it is a very simple fix, but I can't find it! (I did check the titlesec package documentation, but was not successful.)

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=20mm, right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm,includehead=true,headsep=3pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[pdfview=FitB,hidelinks]{hyperref}

    

%Format the section titles/headings
\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth}{#1}}}
    
\titleformat{name=\section}[hang]
    {\Large}
    {}
    {0pt}
    {\colorsection}
    
\titlespacing{\section}{-5mm}{10mm}{\baselineskip}



%change how the TOC appears
\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\l@section}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\hacknumberline}{}{}

\newcommand\hacknumberline{\let\numberline\my@numberline}

\def\my@numberline #1%
   {\vbox{\hbox{\kern-\fboxsep
                \color{blue!20}%
                \rlap{\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth+\fboxsep}{1pt}}%
                \kern\fboxsep
                }%
          \nointerlineskip
          \hb@xt@ \@tempdima
              {\kern-\fboxsep\colorbox{blue!20}{\color{black}#1.}% I added a dot here
               \hfil}%
         }%
    }
\makeatother
    

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother


\title{MyTOC}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Section 1}
This is Section 1
\subsection{Subsection 1}
Hello

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of package `titlesec`, your command `\colorsection` gets only the title of the section as an argument, so you have to take care of the numbering yourself. Below, I have added `\arabic{section}\quad`; modify it as needed.

```
\newcommand{\colorsection}[1]{%
    \colorbox{blue!20}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth}{\arabic{section}\quad#1}}}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!! (I would upvote, but I don't have enough reputation...)